# Restlet - trouble attaching Resource class with Router

Tags: java, rest, restlet

Prototyping with Restlet 2.1.0, Java SE version, I am having trouble mapping ServerResource classes to urls.  I've tried quite a few variations using the Router.attach method, but nothing has worked.

My current code looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Router router = new Router();
    router.attach("/hello", FirstServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/json", Json.class);

    Application myApp = new Application() {
        @Override
        public org.restlet.Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            router.setContext(getContext());
            return router;
        };
    };

    new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, myApp).start();
}
```

When I browse to `http://localhost:8182/hello` it doesn't do the template match correctly.  Debugging through the source code, I see what happens is that the match logic sees the requested resource as `http://localhost:8182/hello` instead of just `/hello`.  The Restlet code where this happens is here:

```
// HttpInboundRequest.java
// Set the resource reference
if (resourceUri != null) {
    setResourceRef(new Reference(getHostRef(), resourceUri));

    if (getResourceRef().isRelative()) {
        // Take care of the "/" between the host part and the segments.
        if (!resourceUri.startsWith("/")) {
            setResourceRef(new Reference(getHostRef().toString() + "/"
                    + resourceUri));
        } else {
            setResourceRef(new Reference(getHostRef().toString()
                    + resourceUri));
        }
    }

    setOriginalRef(getResourceRef().getTargetRef());
}
```

In the code above, it sees the Resource as *relative*, and therefore changes the requested resource from `/hello` to the full url.  I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm totally stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution by turning on the logging (FINE). I saw this log message:

> By default, an application should be attached to a parent component in
>   order to let application's outbound root handle calls properly.

I don't totally understand what it meant (maybe I have to read docs start to finish?).  Attaching the application to a *VirtualHost* fixed the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    final Router router = new Router();
    router.attach("/hello", FirstServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/json", Json.class);
    router.attachDefault(Default.class);

    Application myApp = new Application() {
        @Override
        public org.restlet.Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            router.setContext(getContext());                
            return router;
        };
    };


    Component component = new Component();
    component.getDefaultHost().attach("/test", myApp);

    new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, component).start();
}
```