# Restlet - Server class handling multiple kinds of resources

Tags: java, rest, restlet-2.0

I cannot understand how to use org.restlet.Server class for handling different kinds of ServerResource's.

I want run:

```
new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, SomeNotYetReady.class).start();
```

and I want to get a different Resource according to the URL entered. For example, browsing to

```
http://myserver:8182/rest/new-customer
```

could be used for inserting a new customer in server database, while

```
http://myserver:8182/rest/new-order
```

could be used for creating a new customer's order, and

```
http://myserver:8182/rest/get-order
```

could be used for orders retrieval.

Is my approach correct? If so, what classes should I write for this purpose, and which class has to be passed to Server constructor?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I have realized that this question is related to [Restlet - trouble attaching Resource class with Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147772/restlet-trouble-attaching-resource-class-with-router), and there is a perfect answer there.

Answer (score 0):

actually launching a Server is fine only for quick code. It is not appropriate for real application. 
I suggest you to have a look at this http://restlet.com/learn/tutorial/2.2/
and for a full example application deployed on GAE: http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/introduction/first-steps/first-application

Basically, you define an Application which can be seen as a container for a set of ServerResource. Then you host this application inside a Component which can be seen as a container for Application.
A Component provides some common services such as a HTTP server connector.

Comment: Problem is that I don't even know what GAE is. Is it a webserver, such as tomcat? is there any good tutorial online for setting it up?