# issue binding context route using Restlet

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm using restlet in a proof-of-concept as follows:

```
    final Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);
    final Router router = new Router(component.getContext().createChildContext());
    router.attachDefault(HttpListener.class);
    component.start();
```

This should give me a URL path of `http://localhost:8182/*`.  However, I just get 404 errors when trying to GET from this URL:

```
http://localhost:8182/      -> 404
http://localhost:8182/xyz   -> 404
```

Restlet isn't routing any requests to my HttpListener class.

My HttpListener class:

```
public class HttpListener extends ServerResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Component component = new Component();
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);
        final Router router = new Router(component.getContext().createChildContext());
        router.attachDefault(HttpListener.class);
        component.start();
    }

    @Get()
    public Representation getDBName() {
        String body = "hello, world";
        Representation representation = new StringRepresentation(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        representation.setCharacterSet(CharacterSet.UTF_8);
        return representation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to attach the route as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final Router router = new Router();
    router.attachDefault(HttpListener.class);

    Application myApp = new Application() {
        @Override
        public org.restlet.Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            router.setContext(getContext());
            return router;
        };
    };
    Component component = new Component();
    component.getDefaultHost().attach("/", myApp);

    new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, component).start();
}
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13165900/1033422 for this answer.